# Average Inductor Current in RL Charging Circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, inductor, switching, switching-regulator

Here's a switching circuit. The input Vs is a 24V rectangular pulse at 20kHz frequency with 75% duty cycle. Since the time constant L/R is very much greater than the pulse width, we expect the inductor current to be a triangular wave (i.e. integral of a rectangular wave) at a certain DC offset which is the average current. My problem is, how do you find the average inductor current assuming Vbatt is 13.8V? (Please ignore questions b and c.)

[image]

Comment: What is the average voltage of Vs? What is the Vbat initial voltage? The difference across 0.1 ohm controls the average current. It cannot be solved unless Vbat is known or you assume from b) Vbatt=13.8V or dead at 11.5V if an auto battery.

Comment: Okay, let's say Vbatt is 13.8V.

Comment: Now use Vavg of input and Ohm's law

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that but what about the voltage across the inductor? Shouldn't it be a series of discontinuous sawtooth pulses?

Comment: No , They define Vs as 24 or 0 so it is continuous so all sources are 0 ohm as well as L

Comment: I mean, Vs is 24V or 0V but there is a varying voltage drop across the inductor every time the switch source is turned on or off so shouldn't the voltage across the resistor vary according to the voltage across the inductor?

Comment: No because V=LdI/dt and L/R=1 and 1/f=50us so V across L is neglected but you can compute L/R * dt=1 * 50us/4

Comment: and 1 * 50us *3/4 for the positive ripple is also negl.

Comment: I once put a 3.7V LiPo across a huge 5MVA transformer that was 22H and low Ohm so L/R was huge and dI/dt was V/L=3.7/22H = 0 to 168 mA after one second and when rising to 5A started to rise faster indicating the beginning of core saturation. But here they want the steady state current

Answer (score 1):

Only guidance, not something to copy as is:

The time constant L/R = 1 second. That's a long time when compared to the pulse interval. The current in the inductor does not change remarkably, probably not even measurably during one pulse period. You can well think your pulse source as a constant voltage DC source. The voltage of it is the average pulse voltage.